# Split String and add in combobox in c#

Tags: c#, string, combobox

Im getting a data from a database and adding to combobox.The string contains list of names with comma.

```
DataRow dr = newdt.Rows[i];
TraineeCombo.Items.Add(dr["Trainee"].ToString());
```

It works fine but i want to split the string and add each item to combobox. I tried below methods.

```
 DataRow dr = newdt.Rows[i];
 string TempTr = dr["Trainee"].ToString();
 string[] result = TempTr.Split(new Char[] {','});
 foreach (string s in result)
      {
        if (s.Trim() != "")
        TraineeCombo.Items.Add(s);
       }
```

Second method:

```
String TempTr = dr["Trainee"].ToString();
TraineeCombo.Items.AddRange(TempTr.Split(','));
```

But both methods shows error as

Cannot convert string to char[] and invalid arguments.
I got this piece of sample code from msdn.How can i solve it?

Comment: Which line raises the exception?

Comment: Remove `new Char[] {','}` and replace with `','`. `Split` accepts multiple `char` arguments and not an array of `char`. The other overloads do accept an array, but not the one you're using.

Comment: @MotoSV really? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Code review note: replace `if (s.Trim() == "")` with `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))`

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem using an input like `string TempTr = "Mark,Steve,John";` I could get the correct splitting using your code. Are you sure that you are using the correct quoting around the comma? If you write `TempTr.Split(new Char[] {","});` then the error appears

Comment: What line of code is giving this error? I'm guessing string[] result = TempTr..Split(new Char[] {','});

Comment: @Anu...you are correct with your comment. Is it the `string[] result = TempStr.Split(...)` line that is throwing an exception? Tried the `Split(....)` code and it compiled and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DataRow dr = newdt.Rows[i];
string TempTr = dr["Trainee"].ToString();
string[] result = TempTr.Split(',');
foreach (string s in result)
  {
    if (s.Trim() != "")
    TraineeCombo.Items.Add(s);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if  yourDB is "str" try this:

```
 string str= "Landon,Paris,Tehran,OtherCity";
        var strsplited = str.Split(",".ToCharArray());


        foreach (var VARIABLE in strsplited)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(VARIABLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Convert.ToString(dr["Trainee"])
```

You are probably getting InvalidCastException. One simple reason is that Convert makes the code more readable, the one that will read your code will understand exactly your intention. 
Another solution is to use TryParse. 
Also your split should be like:

```
yourString.Split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

check null for your db column value...

```
        sDataRow dr = newdt.Rows[i];

        object value = dr["Trainee"];
        if (value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            string TempTr = dr["Trainee"].ToString();
            string[] result = TempTr.Split(',');
            foreach (string s in result)
            {
                if (s.Trim() != "")
                    TraineeCombo.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
```